# "Sense Operation Failed" error code when trying to read in the first sector of a hard disk

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dosbox

I'm trying to read in the first sector of the first hard disk in 8086 assembly. I've never tried to do disk access in 8086 assembly before.
I'm using DosBox, and the assembler is MASM ver 6.11.

Here's the program I put together based on information I learned from the wikipedia pages on CHS, and INT 13H.

```
;***************************************************************************;
    TheStack SEGMENT STACK                                                  ;
;***************************************************************************;


    db 64 dup ('THESTACK')                


;***************************************************************************;
    TheStack ENDS                                                           ;
;***************************************************************************;



;***************************************************************************;
    Data SEGMENT                                                            ;
;***************************************************************************;

    sectBuff db 1024 dup ("!")

;***************************************************************************;
        Data ENDS                                                           ;
;***************************************************************************;



;***************************************************************************;
    Code SEGMENT                                                            ;
;***************************************************************************;                                                         
    assume CS:Code,DS:Data                                                  ;
    MAIN PROC                                                               ;
    Start:                                                                  ;
    mov ax, data                                                            ;
    mov ds, ax                                                              ; 
;***************************************************************************;

    mov bx, ds        ;copy ds into es
    mov es, bx
    lea bx, sectBuff  ;bx takes the offset of sectBuff
                      ;now es:[bx] points to sectBuff


    mov ah, 2h  ;select the read sectors function
    mov al, 1h  ;number of sectors to read
    mov ch, 0h  ;cylinder number (0 - 1023, 2 high bits in cl) 
    mov cl, 1h  ;starting sector number (1-63 last 6 bits)
    mov dh, 0h  ;head number
    mov dl, 80h ;first hard drive
    int 13h     


;***************************************************************************;
    mov AH,4CH                                                              ;
    mov AL,0                                                                ;
    int 21H                                                                 ;
    MAIN ENDP                                                               ;
    Code ENDS                                                               ;
    END Start                                                               ;
;***************************************************************************;
```

After running the program, DosBox hangs indefinitely, and nothing is written to sectBuff.

After debugging the program with debugx (a clone of ms-debug), I see that the error code FF is present in the AH register after int 13H is called.

Error code FF corresponds to a "sense operation failed" error according to the Wikipedia page on Int 13H.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does DOSBox support writing to HDs?

Comment: DOSBox doesn't normally emulate a hard disk. If you haven't mounted a hard disk disk image using IMGMOUNT then the INT 13h services won't work.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll test out the program on actual hardware then. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it works perfectly on actual hardware, and after mounting an hdd image in DosBox. Thanks.